# Program appends L to variable name using TCHAR type and TEXT macro

Tags: c++, windows, lpcstr

I'm trying to get the Program Files path, append it another bit of path and then run it.

```
TCHAR programsdir[MAX_PATH];
SHGetFolderPath(NULL,CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86,NULL,NULL,programsdir);
PathAppend(programsdir, TEXT("\\bin\\program.exe"));
LPCSTR pokerpath = TEXT(programsdir);
WinExec(pokerpath ,SW_SHOW);
return pokerpath;
```

Getting this error message when trying to run the above:

`error C2065: 'Lprogramsdir' : undeclared identifier`

Comment: Which of those three steps are you having trouble with? Which line is causing the error? Have you tried creating a minimal example? How long did it take you to compose this question?

Comment: also mention whether this is a compile or runtime error_

Comment: @MoatazElmasry: It's a compile error, see the C2065?

Comment: What did you expect this code to do: `LPCSTR pokerpath = TEXT(programsdir);`? Did you expect it to modify `programsdir`? Copy it? Cast it to a different type of pointer?

Answer (score 2):

`TEXT` is a macro that should be `L` when you are compiling with unicode and nothing otherwise.

So in your case, `TEXT(programsdir)` becomes `Lprogramsdir`. That's why you have this error.

When you are using unicode strings, you have to prefix their declaration with a `L` as in `L"My string content"`

By writing `TEXT("My string content")`, you ensure that it become L"My string content" when using unicode and "My string content" otherwise. This macro allows you to use different encoding without having to modify your raw strings.

It's not used for copy or cast, if that's what you where trying to do.

Comment: It's hard to imagine what reasoning lead to this line: `LPCSTR pokerpath = TEXT(programsdir);` If a new object was being created, how was it to be freed? If not, what was the pointer supposed to point to?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: LPCSTR is a typedef for `const char *`

Comment: @0A0D: Right. So what was that line supposed to do? What was `pokerpath` supposed to point to after that line? A newly-created object? An existing object? Or what? Did the OP think it allocated a string? Did the OP think it changed the contents of `programsdir`? Or copied them? Or what?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I think he thinks that it helps him, when he does not understand that they are just hidden types created by microsoft. TCHAR is a char and LPCSTR is a const char *, so all this funny business using TEXT is silly.

Answer (score 0):

`TCHAR` is a `typedef` for `char`.

`LPCSTR` is a `typedef` for `const char *`.

There is no need to call the `TEXT` macro (Which appends an `L` to your variable name apparently per @olchauvin).

You should be using `strcpy(pokerpath, programsdir);`

or just return `programsdir`. It will decay in to `char *` anyways.

I don't know if you are using UNICODE, so you may need to use one of the special UNICODE functions to copy the strings. Otherwise, just return it.